# How to call the player rect in a seperate module

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently implemented an enemy that shoots at regular intervals at a designated point on the screen. However, upon trying to make this point the player rect, it refused to work. As the enemy class is defined in the rooms module which is then defined in the main game module, I am not quite certain on how to call the player rect in the enemy  module.

Working code as follows:

## Game module

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from pygame.math import Vector2
from enemy import *
from Rooms import Room0


pygame.init()

screen_rect = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')


all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Assign rooms
rooms = []
room = Room0()
rooms.append(room)

current_room_no = 0
current_room = rooms[current_room_no]


# Spawn player

player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list.add(player)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


done = False


# ----- Event Loop

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    current_room.projectiles.update()
    current_room.enemy_sprites.update()



    screen_rect.fill(GREEN)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen_rect)
    current_room.projectiles.draw(screen_rect)
    current_room.enemy_sprites.draw(screen_rect)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## Rooms module

```
import pygame
from enemy import Enemy
import Projectile
from pygame.math import Vector2


class Room(object):
    enemy_sprites = None
    projectiles = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()



class Room0(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        enemy = Enemy(380, 280, self.projectiles)
        self.enemy_sprites.add(enemy)
```

## Player module

```
from constants import *
import pygame


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

## Enemy module

```
from constants import *
import pygame
from Projectile import Bullet
from pygame.math import Vector2

target = Vector2(400, 400)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, projectiles):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.previous_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.shoot_delay = 1000
        self.speed = 12
        self.projectiles = projectiles

    def update(self):

        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.previous_time > self.shoot_delay:
            self.previous_time = now
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, target)
            self.projectiles.add(bullet)
```

## Projectile module

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from pygame.math import Vector2

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, target):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.position = Vector2(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)


        direction = target - self.position

        radius, angle = direction.as_polar()
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, -angle, 1)

        self.velocity = direction.normalize() * 11

    def update(self):

        self.position += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.position
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an answer you want, and an answer you need. Respectively:

**SomeModule.py:**

```
from game import player # imports the Player *instance* you've created in the main module

some_func(player) # as argument
player.another_func # method access
```

Now, that's the way you'd normally access that kind of stuff, and this would be perfectly fine. In this case though:

a) You'll spawn a whole new game loop, because you put the game setup at module scope rather than in some function or, at very least, directly under an `if __name__ == '__main__'`. Importing a module executes all the code in the module scope.

b) The very fact you have to import a non-singleton *instance*, directly, is a code smell - what the very existence of this problem should signal to you is that you likely have a place where your bits of code must be able talk to each other, but you have nothing unambiguously responsible for mediating that process.

So, to address the second part of my promised answer: you should not let this problem occur in the first place - build **something dedicated to managing players and enemies**, import just the class definitions, then instance and interface between them in the manager.

Comment: Thanks for that! Ill get to work on creating something like you suggested